# How to leverage Django's authentication system in Next.js?

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework, next.js

I am developing a web application which has backend written in Django (using Django REST Framework for API) and frontend written in Next.js.

I was considering implementing user authentication in the frontend using tools like PassportJS or Auth0. **But, is there a way to leverage Django's own authentication system and avoid using third-party libraries like the ones mentioned above?**

Comment: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/

Comment: @PavanKumarTS would this allow me to pass the user data back and forth between the backend and the frontend?

Comment: That entirely depends on what type authentication and how you want to implement it.

Comment: Here is the sample token based auth tutorial https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/11/22/how-to-implement-token-authentication-using-django-rest-framework.html

Comment: Would you have any tutorial to point me to related to user authentication using DRF and Next.js? I can not find any...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not consider using in made  django UserCreationForm it is as simple as it looks

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
```

and the user from

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```